# Is there a way to automatically extract a row into another spreadsheet if the cell matches its counter cell in excel?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I am trying to run a formula that does the following:

I have three columns, an account number, recorded amount, and the actual amount. What I'm trying to do is this, if the actual amount is not equal to the recorded amount, I want to pull that line, including the account number, recorded amount, and actual amount, and put it into a separate sheet. I'm trying to get this to happen over the span of about 100 rows. So it would look like this:

```
Account | Recorded Amount | Actual Amount
-----------------------------------------
Company |      $356       |     $356
Company |      $569       |     $569
Company |      $700       |     $705  ** Doesn't match
Company |      $300       |     $320  ** Doesn't match

##Now since the third and fourth rows don't match their respective columns
##The data is then extracted into a separate sheet.

**Separate Spreadsheet**

Account | Recorded Amount | Actual Amount
-----------------------------------------
Company |      $700       |     $705  
Company |      $300       |     $320
```

I've tried using Vlookup and Match functions, but can't seem to figure this one out. Any help would be appreciated!

Attempts:

Attempting to use IF statement, the problem I encounter is not being able to return the whole row. I can return a specific cell but not the entire row.

```
=IF(E5=D5,A5:E5,"") * give a #VALUE error
=IF(E5=D5,E5) * returns selected cell
=VLOOKUP(E15=D15,D15:E299,2,FALSE) * #N/A
```

Tried using it across a sequence, but it'll only return the first cell that is selected, in this case, it would just return 'Company'. I could run this for each row but that's a lot of effort and code to run that piece of code across multiple columns and rows. It's also not scalable.

The main problem I'm having is capturing the entire row. I can extract the value of a specific cell if it matches, but not the entire row of data. I would also accept that Excel is not capable of this. I was able to generate the required results in a couple of lines of code in Python but in Excel, I'm not as fluent and I'm unsure of what path to take.

Comment: In OS there are no restrictions to respond in general. Please avoid introducing noise into your question to attract attention, there are more productive ways to show your progress since you published your question.

Comment: Please let me know any other ways to attract attention to my question. No one has answered or attempted to answer the question since I posted it yesterday. I need to complete this project by Tuesday and I'm stuck. I've found an alternative using Python, but I need to do this in excel.

Comment: 1) Remember that we are on the weekend so there will be fewer users who can help them since they do not visit the site. 2) One method to attract attention is to give a bounty but for this you must gain reputation, another method that already indicates is that you show what you have tried, you have only shown what you have and what you want without showing any effort.

Comment: I posted this Thursday... had 10 views... you're not really offering me much help... yes, I can show all the things I've tried, but they've been unsuccessful. Trust me when I say, I've been working on this for a while with a great deal of effort. It just didn't seem beneficial to post all my failed attempts. Instead of chastising me for posting specifically what I'm looking for, it would be more helpful if you provided me with some guidance on solving the problem.

Comment: Okay.... I'm editing it now and I'll post it again with my attempts... However, if I dont have any responses, I'm going to readjust my title back to the updated title I had in the hopes that I can get some assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Suggested solution

If I understand you correctly, the solution could be the following.

*Sheet1* contains the source data:

[image]

*Sheet2* contains a table with calculated data: only those rows that differ in the values *Recorded* and *Actual*:

[image]

Cells `A2:C9` of *Sheet2* contain formulas. This is the same range of cells like the source data on *Sheet1*. *Sheet2* `A2` contains this formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet1'!$A$2:$C$9,LARGE(N('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$9<>'Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$9)*(ROW('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$9)-ROW('Sheet1'!$B$1)),SUM(N('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$9<>'Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$9))-ROWS(A$1:A1)+1),COLUMNS($A1:A1)),"")}
```

The formula is copied to the other cells up to `C9`. You may adjust cell references to your needs.

*Note that this is an array formula. Omit the curly braces and enter the formula by pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`.*

---

## Explanation

I will try my best...

Let's start with a slightly better readable formula.

```
{=IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        'Sheet1'!$A$2:$C$9,
        LARGE(
            N('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$9<>'Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$9) * (ROW('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$9)-ROW('Sheet1'!$B$1)),
            SUM(N('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$9<>'Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$9)) - ROWS(A$1:A1) + 1
        ),
        COLUMNS($A1:A1)
    ),
    ""
)}
```

### Main definitions

[INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-A5DCF0DD-996D-40A4-A822-B56B061328BD)

> Returns the value of an element in a table or an array, selected by the row and column number indexes.

Usage is `INDEX(array, rowNumber, columnNumber)`.

Example: if `D6` contains `Hello World!` then `INDEX(C3:E20, 4, 2)` returns `Hello World!` (2nd cell in 4th row in the given range)

[LARGE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LARGE-function-3AF0AF19-1190-42BB-BB8B-01672EC00A64)

> Returns the k-th largest value in a data set. You can use this function to select a value based on its relative standing. For example, you can use LARGE to return the highest, runner-up, or third-place score.

Usage is `LARGE(array, k)`.

Example: `LARGE({1,5,5,9,2,7,0,1}, 2)` = `7` (7 is the second largest value)

### Breakdown of the formula

**1) Find row numbers**

It all starts with a comparison of the columns *B* and *C*.

```
'Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$9<>'Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$9
```

Remind that this is an array formula. Thus the result of this comparison is an array containing boolean values.

```
{FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}
```

In the next step the boolean-array is multiplied with the relative row numbers. `ROW('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$9)` returns the absolute row numbers: `{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`. The position of the heading `ROW('Sheet1'!$B$1)` is subtracted. We get the relative row numbers `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`.

Both arrays are multiplied.

```
N('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$9<>'Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$9) * (ROW('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$9) - ROW('Sheet1'!$B$1))
```

Replaced with values:

```
N({FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}) * ({2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} - 1)
```

Resolved:

```
{0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1} * {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

The resulting array contains the relative row numbers of those rows that differ in *B* and *C*.

```
{0,2,0,0,5,6,0,8}
```

**2) Arrange row numbers in desired order**

The result of the `LARGE` function is passed as row number parameter to the `INDEX` function. We want the `INDEX` function to return errors (discussed later) for rows with equal values in columns *B* and *C*. Thus we have to implement some weird logic to calculate the `k` parameter for the `LARGE` function.

```
LARGE(
    N('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$9<>'Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$9) * (ROW('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$9)-ROW('Sheet1'!$B$1)),
    SUM(N('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$9<>'Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$9)) - ROWS(A$1:A1) + 1
),
```

The `SUM` counts rows having differences in columns *B* and *C* `=4`, then the currently viewed row `ROWS(A$1:A1)` is subtracted and `1` is added. We get following values for the `k` parameter of `LARGE`: `4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3`.

```
LARGE({0,2,0,0,5,6,0,8}, k)
```

The resulting values are:

```
2, 5, 6, 9, #NUM!, #NUM!, #NUM!, #NUM!
```

**3) Pick the values**

The `INDEX` function references the source data `'Sheet1'!$A$2:$C$9`. Row numbers are the values we just calculated with `LARGE`, and column number is the currently viewed column `COLUMNS($A1:A1)`.

For the first target row `INDEX` returns the values of the second source row, for the second target row the values of the 5th source row, and so on. From the 5th target row onwards we don't want to display anything. If we would use `2, 5, 6, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0` for the row numbers `INDEX` would write unwanted values in the 5th to 8th line. This is why we wanted `LARGE` to return `#NUM!` for rows with equal values. If `INDEX` is passed `#NUM!` then it also returns `#NUM!`. Finally, we can handle these cases with `IFERROR(..., "")` and get empty cells.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you! Yes that worked, can you explain the coding for me?

Comment: My Solution was inspired by the [Tabellenexperte](https://www.tabellenexperte.de/besser-als-sverweis-alle-werte-finden/) (sorry, but it's German). I updated my answer to contain an explanation.